# Mathematics of signal processing

Tags: reference-request, signal-processing

I've done an undergraduate in electrical and communication engineering. And now after 4 years, I want to pursue masters (graduation) in signal processing and communications. Hence I want to brush up my mathematics concept regarding the same. I need a suggestion for the books to refer.

Comment: Queuing Systems, 2 volumes I think, by L Kleinrock. Shannon's original paper from 1948 too http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf

Comment: Martin Vetterli, Jelena Kovačević, Vivek Goyal, [Foundations of Signal Processing](http://foundationsofsignalprocessing.org), 2014.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this question. In addition to the textbook, you might like to try my YouTube channel. All the videos are categorised and linked from the following website: http://iaincollings.com I'm a professor and I've been building what I like to think of as an on-line video textbook for Signals, Systems, and Digital Communications.

Answer (score 1):

I finally like to answer my own question. After a long search and going through lots of books I found [Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/mathematics-of-signal-processing/A3F20BC5FBB820E923E66C8CCB13B173) book for mathematics of signal processing. it's really a decent book to brush up the maths behind/for signal Processing.

Comment: See a review at https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-mathematics-of-signal-processing